# Exception Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.class'

Tags: mysql, tomcat, servlets, jndi, context.xml

I'm trying to connect Context.xml file to my Demo.java(Servlet) on Eclipse.
**Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'**.
Please let me know where I'm wrong.
Please help.
[Demo.java(servlet) with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtOAE.png)
[Context.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg5LE.png)

mysql-connector jar is added wherever possible. still not able to resolve the exception

Comment: And please copy paste formatted code, not linked images.

Comment: [Here are the reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447) for not posting text content as image. Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `context.xml` has `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.class` mentioned. You should not mention `.class` there. Just mention `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. This is the fully qualified class name. If you add `.class` at the end, then `Driver` becomes the package, and it tries to search for a driver class by name `class` in the `Driver` package, which it won't find.

So,

```
driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```